# Inject external object in a spring bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a noob spring question.
if i have a bean that is dependent on google's gdata api jars. How I represent this in a beans.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean class="com.google.foo.bar.ExternalClass" id="yourExternalBeanName" />
```

Then you can inject this 3rd party bean in your classes. With XML:

```
<property name="yourProperty" ref="yourExternalBeanName" />
```

or annotations:

```
@Inject
private ExternalClass yourProperty;
```